# How to get the whole line where a given word is and store it in a variable?

Tags: c++, find, line, record

i am a beginner in the C++ world, i need to get the whole line where a given word is and store it into a variable.

```
my TXt file has this structure :
clients.txt
085958485 Roland Spellman rolandl@gmail.com 
090545874 KATHLEEN spellman kathleen1@hotmail.com 
056688741 Gabrielle Solis desperate@aol.com
```

so the program requests to the user to enter the id of the person, the id is always the first number or word in the line.
the user enters then 
    090545874
the program has to be able to find the 090545874 in the text file and then get the whole line where it is stored into a variable.

i know how to find a word in a text file but i don't know how to get the whole line into a variable. so at the end my variable has to store

variable = 090545874 KATHLEEN spellman kathleen1@hotmail.com 4878554

after that, i am able to delete the entire line or record.
i use this code to enter the data into the txt file

```
      struct person{       

      char id[10];
      char name[20];
      char lastname[20];
      char email[10];
      } clientdata;

      ofstream clientsfile;
      clientsfile.open ("clientes.dat" , ios::out | ios::app);


      if (clientsfile.is_open())
      {
      cout<<"   ENTER THE ID"<<endl;
      cin>>clientdata.id;
      clientsfile<<clientdata.id<<" ";                              

      cout<<"   ENTER THE NAME"<<endl;
      cin>>datoscliente.name;
      clientsfile<<clientdata.name<<" ";

      cout<<"   ENTER THE LAST NAME"<<endl;
      cin>>clientdata.lastname;
      clientsfile<<clientdata.lastname<<" ";

      cout<<"   ENTER THE LAST EMAIL"<<endl;
      cin>>clientdata.email;
      clientsfile<<clientdata.email<<" ";
```

then i request to the eu to enter the id 
 and what i need to do is not to find the id only, it's to get the whole line where the id is
so if the user enters 090545874 , i need to find it in the text file , but i need to get teh whole line in this case 090545874 KATHLEEN spellman kathleen1@hotmail.com 
so i need to store that into a new variable
    string newvariable;
    newvariable = 090545874 KATHLEEN spellman kathleen1@hotmail.com

Comment: Possibly using a struct with one member for each piece of data would be better than putting the whole thing into one variable.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with C++ but in Java there is a .getLine() function.  I'm sure there is something similar in c++

Comment: I hope those email addresses are made up? If they are real, I suggest removing to avoid spam bots getting to them

Comment: @Tony: Wow, does that mean I might have Gabrielle Solis's actual email address?! Impressive for a fictional character, and that's quite a remarkable email address too!

Comment: yes, i use a struct to put that data on the txt file

Comment: Smells like you should be feeding the file directly to a database or spreadsheet.  Look up "comma separated Values" or "CSV" formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank all of you for your answers, I finally figured it out , I used this function :

```
bool mostshow(int option, string id)
{
 if (option== 2 && id== id1)
 return true;

 if (option== 3 && id== id1)
 return true;

 return false;

}

and this other one

void showline(string field1, string field2, string field3, string field4, string field5, string field6,    string field7)
{   
string store;
store = field1+" "+field2+" "+field3+" "+field4+" "+field5+" "+field6+" "+field7;

cout<<endl;
}

and then in the main 

ifstream myfile("clients.dat", ios::in);    
                  if (!myfile)
                     {
                     cerr <<"   CANNOT OPEN THE FILE!!"<<endl;
                     exit(1); 
                     }

                  option=2;

                  myfile >> field1 >> field2 >> field3 >> field4 >>field5 >> field6 >> field7;



                  while (!myfile.eof())
                  {
                        if (mostshow(option, id))
                           {
                            showline(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7);
                           }


                  myfile >> field1 >> field1 >> field1 >> field1 >>field1 >> field1 >> field1;

                  } 

                  myfile.close();
```

option variable is part of a switch statement which asks if you want to delete or modify the record, 2 means modify , 3 delete

Answer (score 2):

To read files one line at a time, you can use the `std::getline` function defined in the `<string>` header (I'm assuming you're using the `fstream` library as well):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ifstream input_file("file.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (true) {
        std::getline(input_file, line);
        if (input_file.fail())
            break;

        // process line now
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What's nice about the function `std::getline`, though, is that it allows for this much cleaner syntax:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::ifstream input_file("file.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(input_file, line)) {
        // process line now
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you're reading the file, but the [fgets function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifstream`, `getline` and `unordered_map`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

ifstream infile("mytextfile.txt");

if (!infile) {
    cerr << "Failure, cannot open file";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

unordered_map<string, string> id2line;
string id, line;

while (getline(infile, line)) {
    stringstream strstm(line);
    strstm >> id;
    id2line[id] = line;
}
```

Now you can do

```
cout << "Please enter an id: " << endl;

string id;
cin >> id;

try {
    // unordered_map::at throws an std::out_of_range exception when the key doesn't exist
    string line = id2line.at(id);
    cout << "Info:\n    " << line << endl;
} catch (out_of_range& e) {
    cout << "No information by that id." << endl;
}
```

Comment: i think i am not able to perform the above solution, i get an error unordered_map<string, string> id2line;
 not declared.

Comment: @huskerone you have to `#include <unordered_map>` and put `using namespace std;` at the top of your file/function.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a structure and have the structure read in its data by overloading the stream extraction operator:

```
struct Record
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string email_addr;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record&r)
{
    input >> r.id;
    input >> r.first_name;
    input >> r.last_name;
    getline(input, r.email_addr);
    return input;
}
```

**Edit 1:**
Usage:

```
ifstream input_file("mydata.text");
Record r;
std::map<unsigned int, Record> container;
while (input_file >> r)
{
    unsigned int id = r.id;
    container[id] = r;
}
```

As far as storage is concerned look up the `std::map` structure and copy the ID field and use it as the key.

I still suggest that this work is a better candidate for a database or spreadsheet.